# Is there a non-bacterial source of lipopolysacchrides

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, immune-system

I am wondering if there are any other non-bacterial sources of LPS. To my understanding, lipopolysacchrides (LPS) are components of the outer leaflet of gram-negative bacteria, but are there any other sources of LPS such as fungi?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Lipopolysacchrides have been found in eukaryotes. The most famous example is green algae from Genus [*Chlorella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorella).

According to Armstrong et al., (2002):

> The lipopolysaccharides (LPS) are ubiquitous components of the outer leaflet of the outer membrane of all gram-negative bacteria and are the principal toxic products of these organisms (1). The membrane anchor of LPS is lipid A, a central phosphodisaccharide unit that is attached to multiple -hydroxy fatty acid chains. LPS also contains the novel sugar, 3-deoxy-D-mannooctulosonic acid (KDO). Although generally **believed to be restricted to prokaryotes**, specifically the gram-negative eubacteria and the cyanobacteria (2), an LPS-like molecule has recently been **reported from a eukaryote**, the green alga *Chlorella sp.*, strain NC64A. (emphases mine)

Also, for further discussion on LPS in eukaryotes, please see *[Histochemical Evidence for Lipopolysaccharide (Endotoxin) in Eukaryotes](http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/BBLv207n2p172?journalCode=bbl)*.

Source:

- [Armstrong, P., Armstrong, M., Pardy, R., Child, A. and Wainwright, N. (2002). Immunohistochemical Demonstration of a Lipopolysaccharide in the Cell Wall of a Eukaryote, the Green Alga, Chlorella. The Biological Bulletin, 203(2), pp.203-204](http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.2307/1543397?journalCode=bbl).